# May an IFR aircraft be instructed to "squawk VFR" if it goes around while executing a visual approach?

Tags: air-traffic-control, instrument-flight-rules, visual-flight-rules, visual-approaches

A pilot on an IFR flight plan is executing a visual approach to a towered airport.

The pilot executes a go-around due to gusting winds and notifies the tower controller. The controller asks his intentions. He replies that he would like to make another attempt to land at the airport. The controller instructs: "Squawk VFR and enter a left downwind for runway 5."

Is the instruction to squawk VFR proper? Are the rules different under FAA/EASA/ICAO regulations?

Comment: Curious about what Class airspace it was.  I was reading Class D controllers only "use visual means to identify and separate aircraft".

Comment: Ryan, he intends to land after going around.  Robert, yes - tower controllers are primarily visual.

Comment: Were you on an IFR plan or simply shooting practice approaches?  It's somewhat "normal" if shooting practice approaches and you have not informed tower of your intent to do multiple approaches.  If you are on an IFR plan and did not agree to cancel IFR, it's unusual.

Comment: Voting to reopen after editing the question to clarify what I believe was OP's intent: by "requesting to land" the pilot means he is on the upwind leg, and is conveying that he wants to attempt another visual approach at the airport (instead of, e.g., diverting to an alternate airport).

Answer (score 8):

No, that scenario does not sound normal to me. For one thing, **a visual approach is an IFR procedure**. Instructing the crew to change to a VFR squawk makes it sound like the controller is suddenly treating the flight as a VFR flight, which makes no sense. A controller is never allowed to just cancel IFR; going from IFR to VFR must always be explicitly requested by the crew ("cancelling my IFR flight"). We are not even allowed to *suggest* a flight to change to VFR, the idea has to come from the pilot.

Besides, it makes no sense that the controller would change the squawk code of a (presumably) already identified flight to a non-discreet code (1200/7000) since radar identification would then be lost and it would be impossibly to continue to provide radar service.

If the example you provide is a real one, there is obviously a reason for the controller doing what they did, however, based on the limited information you give here, it is hard to see what the reason would be. Maybe if we knew the whole picture, it would make more sense.

Comment: "We are not even allowed to suggest a flight to change to VFR" When landing at an non-towered airport in the US, Approach will ask if you have the field in sight and, if so, will tell you to cancel "with flight serivice on the ground or with me". You might argue the latter's technically not a suggestion to cancel now in the air, but that is how pilots interpret it in practice and, at least for GA, nearly always agree.

Comment: @StephenS Which makes sense, if you are landing at a VFR-only aerodrome (one with no instrument approach). You can't land there IFR. But that's not something enforced by ATC, that's an aerodrome specific restriction that you planned for yourself when you planned the flight.

Comment: @J.Hougaard Most public non-towered airports here have an RNAV approach these days, and many already had NDB, VOR or even ILS approaches, so you could stay IFR to the ground if you insist, but Approach will suggest canceling iff they clear you for the visual.

Comment: @J.Hougaard At least in the US, controllers will make the comment that Stephen mentioned even if the airport has instrument approaches. Many US airports have instrument approaches but no towers, meaning that the pilot has to cancel IFR himself. ATC can't release other IFR traffic into or out of the airport until they receive the cancellation so it's easier for everyone if pilots cancel when airborne if they can. But it's always the pilot's decision, not ATC's, as you said.

Comment: @Pondlife OK, I guess that's because the US has a slightly special way of dealing with IFR/VFR and opening and closing flightplans. See related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35056/who-closes-an-airlines-ifr-flight-plan-and-when

Comment: @J. Hougaard, it looks like you may be a contoller in Scandanavia? Because your rules might be different... I am assuming that the original questions was from the U.S., but if I am wrong then your answer may be more appropriate.  Otherwise this is a common practice in the U.S. as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelHall I wonder why you would make the assumption, since there is nothing in the question to indicate that OP is wondering specifically about US procedures. As such, I have answered in accordance with common practices, not something related to any specific country.

Comment: @J Hougaard, I have my reasons for making this assumption, but I don’t think it is important to list them here.  My point is that I don’t agree that your answer reflects a global common practice.  Specifically, you mention that if the squawk code was changed “radar identification would be lost and it would be impossible to continue to provide radar service.”  However, radar service is not provided in the visual tower pattern, so if the pilot accepts a turn to downwind in the tower pattern it is apparent that radar services are no longer needed or wanted.

Comment: @MichaelHall I absolutely use radar as a tool for traffic in the visual circuit, and I also have IFR traffic in the circuit almost daily. I think most people would agree that the most common practice within aviation is one that complies with ICAO standards, which the FAA is notoriously bad at doing.

Comment: Fair enough, I can't dispute how you may use radar as a tower controller.  Admittedly most of my flight time is military, but I have ALWAYS been instructed to stop squaking whenever doing touch and goes in the VFR tower pattern.

Comment: @expeditedescent In the US, most class D tower controllers are not radar certified. Many D towers don’t even have a radar display, and those that do may officially only be allowed to use it to help them visually identify traffic. (Class B/C towers are different.) Things are weird over here.

Comment: I take issue with the idea that an aircraft has to be squawking a discrete code in order to be radar identified. This is categorically untrue in my (FAA) experience; one can even provide radar services to a radar-identified aircraft that does not have a transponder at all.

Comment: @randomhead Fair point. But assuming an aircraft was assigned a discrete code - in that case, the identification would most likely be based on that code, so if it were changed, identification would be lost (at least until another form of identification could be established)

Comment: @expedite, again I disagree. A discrete beacon code makes it *easier* for a system (whether an automated computer system or an "organic" air traffic controller) to track a target. But they can track and maintain the identity of any target shown on the scope, primary or secondary, whether squawking no code, a non-discrete code, or a discrete code. Would it require some work to re-enter the identification of the aircraft *into the radar system*? Probably. But a target squawking VFR does not mean the integrity of that radar target has been lost.

Comment: @randomhead I'm not talking about the radar track, I'm talking about the identification of that track. Legally, the identification would be lost - even if, practically, it maybe wouldn't

Comment: "Identification" in my vocabulary refers to the controller seeing a target on the scope and correlating that target with a particular pilot talking on the frequency. It is true that the *automation system* will no longer keep the datablock information on a track when the pilot squawks VFR, but the *radar system* will keeping tracking the target and *radar identification* will not be lost.

Comment: I understand why ATC can't unilaterally cancel IFR, but why would suggesting it be a problem?

Comment: @Someone Because the pilot might feel pressured into going VFR in marginal weather conditions

Answer (score 3):

You are typically not operating under IFR in the tower controlled traffic pattern if in the United States, so the short answer is yes.

It is not unusual at all to shoot an instrument approach to a runway, execute an option, (i.e. touch and go or low approach) and then turn downwind into the tower landing pattern.  Generally tower will ask you to squawk standby to declutter approach control’s scope.

It is correct that when cleared for a visual approach you are still on an IFR clearance.  However, what is imporant is the pilots specific words to the controller after aborting the landing:  If the pilot stated “missed approach” and began executing the IFR missed approach procedures he/she should expect to continue to be given IFR handling, i.e. vectors by the approach controller to set up for another instrument approach.  This is especially true if still talking on approach control’s frequency.

However, if the pilot is on tower frequency, weather is VMC and the tower pattern is open, and for fuel or other reasons the pilot desires to turn downwind immediately after aborting a landing, the request should be stated unambiguously:  For example something like, “Tower, N123WP going around, cancel IFR, request left/right closed traffic for landing”.  This makes the intention to remain VFR in the pattern to expedite landing clear, and approval from tower along with a request to change squawk would be entirely appropriate.

The pilot in this case stated "going around" and it sounds like tower made a reasonable assumption about intentions based on weather conditions and the fact that the pilot had previously requested visual to a full stop.  (Requesting an ILS approach to the option could imply multiple practice instrument approaches might be desired for training...)

If this is not what the pilot wanted, it needs to be rebuked clearly and immediately.  For example, “Negative, N123WP is executing the missed approach, request IFR vectors for another visual/ILS/RNAV approach runway 25.”

Instead the pilot accepted tower's clearance to turn downwind into the VFR pattern, and the change to a 1200 code was proper.

Comment: You may not be operating on a full set of IFR instructions (i.e. heading/route and locked-down altitude) but you *should* be afforded IFR separation in the traffic pattern, if the go-around was unintentional. Reference: [7–4–1 (a) and (b).](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap7_section_4.html) Read between the lines for (a) and (b).

If you're shooting instrument approaches and request to terminate an approach with "option tower" that *does* imply cancellation of IFR after completing the option and you will be afforded VFR separation in the pattern.

Comment: @randomhead, I’m not quite sure what you are trying to say here.... What do you mean by “a full set of IFR instructions”?  And are you implying that both IFR and VFR can mingle in the tower traffic pattern, and tower controllers will be expected to manage them both somehow?

Comment: Late response, sorry. Yes, an aircraft executing an unplanned missed approach in VMC may enter the "VFR" traffic pattern for a runway and retain their IFR clearance despite not receiving IFR instructions (heading and altitude). This is dependent on traffic considerations; if there are other IFR inbounds ATC needs to maintain appropriate **airborne** separation (3NM), which may preclude this "traffic pattern" option and the a/c will *instead* be given a heading and altitude and shipped to departure. ATC will continue to provide **runway** separation between all aircraft (IFR and VFR) as normal.

Comment: If an IFR aircraft is coming in on an instrument approach and is *planning* on going around (or performing a touch-and-go) and then staying with Tower for pattern work, the IFR flight is considered completed, and IFR is automatically cancelled, upon completion of the approach. Then an instruction to "squawk VFR in the pattern" would be appropriate. But if the aircraft was supposed to be a full-stop landing and the missed approach was unplanned, ATC cannot cancel their IFR flight plan for them. [cont...]

Comment: The pilot *could* say something like "Going around, request to stay in the pattern" (which is **not** a request to cancel IFR). Then the controller might say "Roger, make [left/right] traffic" or they could say "Unable IFR closed traffic due to IFR inbound, say intentions." Then the pilot has to decide whether to *explicitly cancel IFR* and continue in the pattern VFR, or accept a heading and altitude for resequencing by Approach. Except for the situation of a planned T/G followed by pattern work, ATC *cannot* consider an IFR flight plan terminated until the pilot explicitly says "Cancel IFR."

Comment: @randomhead, I have never heard of co-mingling IFR and VFR traffic in the tower pattern.  That's not to say it isn't permissible, just that I have never observed it to happen and it goes against my paradigm of the tower pattern being VFR only.  Why might a pilot want to stay IFR once you have committed to flying the pattern?  How might a tower controller without radar ensure IFR separation is met?  And what might the IFR clearance and instructions on the upwind leg be?  (i.e. "cleared to ___ via visual approach, maintain pattern altitude"?)

Comment: Beyond my personal paradigm, IFR implies navigating primarily by reference to instruments, which doesn't really fit with flying the traditional pattern.  I'm not sure how to reconcile this...

Comment: It would be very rare, I agree, but the book says it's a possibility. The pilot may want to retain their IFR clearance because their OPSPEC says they can't cancel in the air, or any other reason. If the tower controller (whether with radar or not) can't ensure IFR separation they don't permit the operation in the first place. There would be no "clearance;" as 7–4–1 (linked above) says: "aircraft executing a go-around may ... enter the traffic pattern for landing and an altitude assignment is not required. The pilot is expected to climb to pattern altitude." The clearance limit is unchanged.

Comment: IFR implies *navigating* by reference to instruments, but in the traffic pattern the need for navigation is minimal; the pilot maneuvers by reference to the ground and maintains situational awareness via the big ol' window at the front of the plane, just as they did when coming in for a visual approach in the first place.

Comment: @randomhead, thanks for clarifying your point.

Answer (score 3):

FAA answer.

**No, the instruction to "Squawk VFR"** (code `1200`) **would not be proper in this case.** But there can be nuances.

First of all (and this is an extremely pedantic point), *just because the controller said "Squawk VFR" does not mean they are no longer providing IFR separation*. Yes, yes, of course it is a near-certainty that in this situation, the controller is telling the pilot to squawk VFR because they think the pilot wants to maintain VFR. But it is theoretically possible for a controller to maintain the radar identification of *any* aircraft squawking *any* code (or even no code at all, if there is sufficient primary radar coverage) and provide IFR separation to that target. Theoretically, of course.

So the real question is:

> Is the controller correct in assuming that a pilot’s request to immediately return to the airport and attempt another landing, following a go-around while executing a missed approach, is a request to cancel IFR?

And again the answer is **no**, this would not be a correct assumption.

The phrase "cancel IFR" appears several times in the 7110.65. The most important one comes right at the beginning of the document, paragraph [2–1–4 **Operational Priority**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_1.html#OTJ2b2JACK):

> ***NOTE-***
> *It is solely the pilot's prerogative to cancel an IFR flight plan.*

ATC is not allowed to solicit cancellation of IFR. The pilot must *explicitly* state that they wish to cancel their IFR flight plan, to which ATC's proper response is: "*(Call sign) IFR CANCELLATION RECEIVED*" ([4–2–10**b**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap4_section_2.html#$paragraph4-2-10)). If the pilot does not hear this stated, they are well within their rights to assume they are still on an IFR flight plan. The *only* exception to this is if the pilot of an IFR flight is performing an approach and, **prior to** completing the approach, requests to remain in the VFR traffic pattern upon completion. In this case the "flight" is terminated and the aircraft, which had been receiving IFR separation (see [4–8–11**a**1](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap4_section_8.html#l8I294JACK)), will maintain VFR and stay with the Tower controller in the pattern ([4–8–12](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap4_section_8.html#iyJ2eeJACK)). In this situation the controller saying "Squawk VFR" is purely a housekeeping task to make sure the radar scope reflects reality, namely, the aircraft was VFR as soon as they began the "go" portion of their touch-and-go.

An *unplanned* go-around by an aircraft executing a visual approach is handled differently. Paragraph [7–4–1 **Visual Approach**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap7_section_4.html) is the relevant rule, and the entire paragraph is germane to the discussion, so I have copied it below:

> A visual approach is an ATC authorization for an aircraft on an IFR flight plan to proceed visually and clear of clouds to the airport of intended landing. A visual approach is not a standard instrument approach procedure and has no missed approach segment. An aircraft unable to complete a landing from a visual approach must be handled as any go-around and appropriate IFR separation must be provided until the aircraft lands or the pilot cancels their IFR flight plan.
>
> - **a.** At airports with an operating control tower, aircraft executing a go-around may be instructed to enter the traffic pattern for landing and an altitude assignment is not required. The pilot is expected to climb to pattern altitude and is required to maintain terrain and obstruction clearance. ATC must maintain applicable separation from other aircraft.
> - **b.** At airports without an operating control tower, aircraft executing a go-around are expected to complete a landing as soon as possible or contact ATC for further clearance. ATC must maintain separation from other IFR aircraft.

Notice the difference between **a** and **b**. At an untowered airport ATC will only provide separation between the go-around aircraft and other IFR aircraft, which is the only separation IFR aircraft ever receive in Class E airspace.

At a towered airport, ATC *may* instruct the aircraft to enter the tower pattern, and an altitude assignment is not necessary. The controller will provide "applicable" separation from other aircraft; what this means depends on when the the airspace is Class B, C, or D.

In this situation the aircraft is still IFR, despite being in the VFR traffic pattern. Their clearance limit was the destination airport, and it remains so; they were cleared for a visual approach, and they remain so cleared. They are maneuvering visually and clear of clouds for a landing on the assigned runway.

How the separation is maintained is up to the tower controller. They may call the approach controller and request that no arrivals be cleared for approaches to the airport, thereby effecting *non-radar* or *procedural* separation between the aircraft and any IFR arrivals. Or they could coordinate a radar point-out with the approach controller, thus putting the responsibility on them to keep their traffic farther than 3NM/1000' from the go-around aircraft. Or they could use visual separation, whether pilot-applied or tower-applied; visual separation is a valid form of IFR separation, *so long as* some other form of separation exists before and after the application of vis sep; this means the pilots must have each other in sight, or the controller must have both aircraft in sight, before the aircraft get within three miles of each other.

If the controller is unable to ensure applicable IFR separation, they can say so:

> **ATC:** Unable IFR closed traffic due to IFR inbound. Say intentions.

Then *the pilot* must decide whether to explicitly say "We'll cancel IFR and enter the pattern" or "Request vectors for another approach."

In no situation should the controller *assume* the pilot wants to cancel IFR without hearing them say so in no uncertain terms.

Answer (score -1):

Since you were on an IFR visual approach and have "gone around" after your 1st landing attempt, and are in the landing pattern curcuit, weather permitting, why not do what the tower says?

There may be different procedures for IFR approaches and go arounds. They may have slotted you to "fit in" for left downwind for runway 5 VFR.  Switching (to 1200) and landing seems to get it done.  Unless you leave the landing pattern or do not follow their instructions, there does not seem to be any harm.

Comment: It would also help to be clear about approach (as flying into the towers airspace) as compared with being in the pattern and going around.

Comment: We were IFR and cleared for the visual approach.  Over the threshold and winds gusted strongly.  The PIC decided to go around, powered up and stopped his decent.  He then advised the tower he was "going around" (not "missed").  The Tower asked his intentions and he said he still wished land.  TheTower then said:  Okay squawk 12) and enter a left downwind and brought us around to land.  Those are the complete facts.

Comment: There are different procedures for aborting a landing if you are operating visually under IFR vs VFR that need to be clearly understood by instrument rated pilots.  This response doesn't really answer the question.